# get the digits that are part of a string and then perform a sorting of strings

Tags: java

Say that you have an array containing strings:

```
arr1={"sell 1, time 4, item 4", "buy 3, time 2, item 5"}
```

you want to sort the elements by "time" in ascending order, how could that be done?
So you would have:

```
arr1={"buy 3, time 2, item 5", "sell 1, time 4, item 4"}
```

Maybe merge each string and iterate through each character until you encounter a digit?

I tried doing the following:

```
    String[] arr1={"sell 1, time 4, item 4", "buy 3, time 2, item 5"};
    String singleString = arr1[0];
    int indexOfNumber=singleString.indexOf("time")+5;
    
    System.out.println(singleString.charAt(indexOfNumber));
```

I'm thinking a for loop somewhow but cant think of how.

Comment: Break this down into smaller pieces. For example, one step writing a method that will parse the string into more meaningful pieces of data. Then after you have that method you can apply it to every string in the array. Then finally you can sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the Java Streams API.

#### 1. Model the thing you're working with

Your comma-separated string represents *something*. What is it? I called it an `Event`, with the properties

- *action*, either buy or sell;
- *quantity*, the number behind the action;
- *time*, the number behind the text "time"; and
- *item*, the number behind the text "item".

You could now create a model with just that:

```java
record Event(String action, int quantity, int time, int item) { }
```

<sup>Note: *records* are available since Java 16. If you are running a lower Java version, then you need to create a class instead. Make sure you create a constructor accepting and setting all fields, and make sure you create getters. Note that for records, the compiler automatically creates accessor methods with the same name as the fields.</sup>

#### 2. Make a method that is able to parse a string into an `Event`

Your input string, for example `"sell 1, time 4, item 4"` seems to have a fixed structure. What happens in the below piece of code, is that I assume that this is always the case here. If we split by either a space or a comma-followed-by-a-space, then we have six elements (with indexes 0 - 5). Those six elements each contain a piece of information fitting in our model:

```java
Event parseEvent(String input) {
    String[] parts = input.split(",? ");
    String action = parts[0];
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int time = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
    int item = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);
    return new Event(action, quantity, time, item);
}
```

#### 3. Stream over the elements, converting those comma-separated strings to beautiful `Event` models, then sort by the `time` property of your model:

```java
Stream.of(arr1)
    .map(element -> parseItem(element)) // Convert string to Event instance
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Event::time))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: FWIW, you can use the method reference `this::parseItem`, instead of a lambda. Don’t hold me to it, but I think coding convention prefers the former over the latter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to get the number
following will get you the number as a string
 `"time (\d)"`
you can then sort them

Answer (score 0):

If the string names are constant length (they are in your example), then you can simply count the number of characters and use the time value for sorting. For example, the first time value starts at index 14.
If the names are not constant length, you can use regex to extract the time value from each string.
Alternatively, you can also split each string by delimiter `,`, and then split the 2nd element again by white space, and pick up the last element.

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array use `Arrays.sort` with a `Comparator`. In your case the comparison is on a field you would find with a regular expression.

So:

```
Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("time (\\d+)");
Function<String,Integer> getTime = s -> {
    Matcher matcher = timePattern.matcher(s);
    return matcher.find() ? Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) : 0;
};
Comparator<String> sortByTime = Comparator.comparingInt(getTime);
```

You can then sort an array as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(array, sortByTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows.

```
String[] arr1 = { "sell 2, time 3", "sell 1, time 4, item 4",
        "buy 3, time 2, item 5", "sell 6, time 1, item 8" };
```

- first, use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`<sup>*</sup> to hold the string and the sort criteria.
- then sort on the `value` portion of the entry.
- extract the `key` portion
- and return as an array.

```
arr1 = Arrays.stream(arr1).map(
        str -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>(
                str, extract(str)))
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(Integer::compare))
        .map(Entry::getKey).toArray(String[]::new);

for (String s : arr1) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

prints

```
sell 6, time 1, item 8
sell 3, time 2, item 5
sell 2, time 3, item 9
sell 1, time 4, item 4
```

Here is the helper method to extract the `time` value.

- use a regex to capture the specific field value
- and return as an Integer.

```
public static Integer extract(String str) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("time\\s+(\\d+)").matcher(str);
    m.find();
    return Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
}
```

<sup>*</sup>
For large lists, I prefer using an `Entry` since the `extract` method is only called once per value and not for each comparison.